# How do I write multiple dataframes to excel using python and download the results using streamlit?

Tags: python, excel, streamlit

I have a Python script using streamlit, that allows the user to upload certain excel files, then it automatically runs my anslysis on it, and then I want them to download the results in xlsx format using the streamlit download button. However, I know how to make them download one dataframe to a csv, but not an xlsx file using the streamlit download button, which is what I want to do.

Here's what I've tried so far, and this is after my analysis where I'm just trying to create the download button for the user to download the results that are stored in 3 different dataframes:

```
Import pandas as pd
Import streamlit as st

# arrived_clean, booked_grouped, and arrived_grouped are all dataframes that I want to export to an excel file as results for the user to download. 

def convert_df():
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter('test_data.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
    arrived_clean.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Cleaned', startrow=0, startcol=0, index=False)
    booked_grouped.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Output', startrow=0, startcol=0, index=False)
    arrived_grouped.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Output', startrow=0, startcol=20, index=False)
    writer.save()

csv = convert_df()

st.download_button(
     label="Download data",
     data=csv,
     file_name='test_data.xlsx',
     mime='text/xlsx',
 )
```

When I first run the streamlit app locally I get this error:

> "NameError: name 'booked_grouped' is not defined"

I get it because I haven't uploaded any files yet. After I upload my files the error message goes away and everything runs normally. However, I get this error and I don't see the download button to download my new dataframes:

> RuntimeError: Invalid binary data format: <class 'NoneType'> line 313,
> in marshall_file raise RuntimeError("Invalid binary data format: %s" %
> type(data))

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? It's the last piece I have to figure out.

Comment: `convert_df()` doesn't return anything. Your 'csv' is **NoneType**

Answer (score 2):

> When I first run the streamlit app locally I get this error:
>
> > "NameError: name 'booked_grouped' is not defined"

Assuming your code

```
booked_grouped = st.fileuploader('Something.....`)
```

You can use the below method to skip the error

```
if booked_grouped:
    # All your code inside this indentation
```

#### To Download excel

Convert all `dataframes` to one single excel

```
# Function to save all dataframes to one single excel
def dfs_tabs(df_list, sheet_list, file_name):

    output = BytesIO()

    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(file_name,engine='xlsxwriter')   
    for dataframe, sheet in zip(df_list, sheet_list):
        dataframe.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet, startrow=0 , startcol=0)   
    writer.close()

    processed_data = output.getvalue()
    return processed_data

# list of dataframes 
dfs = [df, df1, df2]

# list of sheet names
sheets = ['df','df1','df2']
```

*Note that the data to be downloaded is stored in memory while the user is connected, so it's a good idea to keep file sizes under a couple of hundred megabytes to conserve memory.*

```
df_xlsx = dfs_tabs(dfs, sheets, 'multi-test.xlsx')
st.download_button(label=' Download Current Result',
                                data=df_xlsx ,
                                file_name= 'df_test.xlsx')
```

Answer (score 2):

The Pluviophile's answer is correct, but you should use `output` in pd.ExcelWriter instead of `file_name`:

```
def dfs_tabs(df_list, sheet_list, file_name):

    output = BytesIO()

    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(output, engine='xlsxwriter')   
    for dataframe, sheet in zip(df_list, sheet_list):
        dataframe.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet, startrow=0 , startcol=0)   
    writer.save()

    processed_data = output.getvalue()
    return processed_data
```